# Is there any file that accurev reads when login?

Tags: accurev

In linux, I need once I login to accurev, the PS1 changes to the following:

suppose my workspace placed in the path `~/myfiles/accurev/ws/myworkspace`

```
<username>@<machineName> : ACCUREV >
```

so, when I for example cd to `~/myfiles/accurev/ws/myworkspace/myproject1/org/daz/` ,
the PS1 be :

```
<username>@<machineName> : ACCUREV/myproject1/org/daz >
```

Comment: There are a number of env variables that AccuRev reads [pg 6 CLI guide]. Though, the shell PS1 is not related to AccuRev. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to change the colors of PS1, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data in `accurev info` to pull this off. But doing it on every prompt load might get annoying since the command takes a few seconds to complete. You could maybe temper that by checking if your PWD has changed and only run it when changing directories.

For example, here's a way to get the path of your PWD relative to accurev info's 'Top':

```
pwd | cut -b`accurev info 2>/dev/null | grep Top | awk '{print $2}' | wc -c | awk '{print $1}'`- 2>/dev/null
```

You could drop this into PS1, but then every prompt will take 1-2 extra seconds. If you wanted to do it only on directory changes you could probably use PROMPT_COMMAND to do the work but only if `PWD != OLDPWD`.

So. Doable? yes. Worth it? hard to say.

Oh, and as for your colors. Check out https://github.com/matschaffer/profile, specifically https://github.com/matschaffer/profile/blob/master/environment.conf for the PS1 definition at the bottom. That should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter your workspaces with the following command:

```
accurev start -w myworkspace
```

Then in your .bashrc add the following:

```
if [ "${ACCUREV_TOPDIR}" != "" ] 
then
  PS1='[\u@\h `pwd | sed -e "s#${ACCUREV_TOPDIR}#ACCUREV#"`]\$ '
else
  PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
fi
export PS1
```

I personally prefer to see the workspace as well like:

```
PS1='[\u@\h `pwd | sed -e "s#${ACCUREV_TOPDIR}#WS(${ACCUREV_WSPACE})#"`]\$ '
```